# Div blocking clicking links below

Tags: html, css, hyperlink

I have a page on Pen
https://codepen.io/nenadmail/pen/KmRbGO

The navigation bar on top hides when you scroll down, then unhides as you scroll back up. However, any links near the navigation bar as you scroll up are unclickable under the navbar. How can I make the links under the navigation bar header clickable?

Thanks!

```
<header class="header" role="banner">
    <div class="maintop">
        <nav>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#services">Services</a></li>
                <li><a href="#clients">Clients</a></li>
                <li><a href="#about">About</a></li>
                <li><a href="#contact">Contact</a></li>
            </ul>
        </nav>
    </div>
    <div class="maintopL">
        <a href="#home">
            <h1 id="mainlogo">N2 Mixology</h1>

        </a>
    </div>
</header>

<p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting 
industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever 
since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and 
scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only 
five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, rem 
aining essentially unchanged. <a href ="#">I want this link to work 
even when it is near the nav bar</a>It was popularised in the 1960s 
with the release of Letraset sheets containing. </p>
<p> Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing 
software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.Lorem 
Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. 
Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 
1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it 
to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, 
but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially 
unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset 
sheets containing. </p>
<p>Lorem Ipsum passages, <a href ="#">I want this link to work even 
when it is near the nav bar</a>and more recently with desktop 
publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem 
Ipsum.Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting 
industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever 
since the 1500s, <a href ="#">I want this link to work even when it is 
near the nav bar</a>when an unknown printer took a galley of type and 
scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only 
five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, 
remaining essentially unchanged.</p>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to be able to click through the `div` you can do this in css with `pointer-events: none;` make sure to add the pointer-events back to the navbar items you do wish to click on:

```
header {
    pointer-events: none;
}
header div {
    pointer-events: all !important;
}
```

https://codepen.io/alessi42/pen/JNeBer

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks. I've tried that. When I do that then the logo is not hiding along with the nav bar. :(

Comment: Question, do you want your logo to appear as it does in the codepen where it is outside of the navbar and overlaps the text? Or do you want it as such https://codepen.io/alessi42/pen/jmQpvO

Comment: Yes. Excatly. That's the look that appears in my codepen. The logo needs to overlap text. But it needs to hide along with the navbar once the user scrolls.

Comment: Interesting. That seemed to work. But now the links in the navbar aren't working the same way.

Comment: Excellent! Thank you very much!